# adding "file" breaks compilation silently

Tags: typescript

I'm facing strange issue. In my module I would like to add definition file

```
declare module "*.md" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

which is in `@foo/bar/m.d.ts` package.
So I added `files` key in my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "build/module",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"],
  "files": ["node_modules/@foo/bar/md.d.ts"]
}
```

When I'm running `tsc` (version 3.4.3) command it compiles without any error but my `build/module` folder is empty. When I remove `files` everything works as expected.

Comment: remove the files?? There are other way to add d.ts files

Comment: Could you be more specific?
I want to add this file to be able to import *.md files

Comment: can you try using the "include" and "exclude" properties ?https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: No, according to docs I should use "files":
"Files included using "include" can be filtered using the "exclude" property. However, files included explicitly using the "files" property are always included regardless of "exclude""